# Convert powerpoint file to web viewer that is also visible on ipad

Tags: document-converter, ipad-app, animation, powerpoint

I want to make my powerpoint slides visible on a web page in such a way the .pptx file cannot be downloaded. However that same webpage should also be accessible from an ipad (this rules out converting the ppt to flash or Silverlight). Finally the ppts contain numerous animations that the users should be able to click through.

Summarizing:

1. Converting .pptx files to an web-based viewer format
2. Visible on ipad
3. User must be able to click through the animations

Does anyone know of a conversion program or file format that ticks all three boxes?

Answer (score 1):

As a file format I would recommend ShockWave Flash. It can be opened by any browser that has Adobe Flash Player plugin installed (all browsers in these days).

[Libreoffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) can open (import) `pptx` files and export them as `swf` objects than can be embedded in any webpage.

You can then embed it in `html` with:

```
<embed src="presentation.swf">
```

You'll have to make the whole `html` file yourself, assuming you have the `swf` in the same folder as your `html`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Presentation</title>
</head>
<body>
<embed src="presentation.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="90%" ></embed>
</body>
</html>
```

Users can click through the presentation, but can't download the `pptx`.

Comment: What about iPad's? the OP specifies that flash **won't work for them - I can't comment on that as I'm not an Apple guy.

Comment: @NickWilde Had no idea about that. Apparently there are solutions http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/ipad/how-get-flash-ipad-3460979/

Comment: The second idea of converting the .pptx files into .swf and embedding that in the html file looks good, will this work on iPad as well?

Comment: @user3559824 Did this work? I thought `.swf` was flash and therefore wouldn't work on iPads